# How to remove every first word from .txt file?

Tags: python, csv

#### Sample data:

```
Apple iPhone 14
Samsung Galaxy S22
Xiaomi Redmi 9
John Doe
```

#### Desired output:

```
iPhone 14
Galaxy S22
Redmi 9
Doe
```

I'd like open a .txt file. How do I remove every first word from every line when file looks similar like there?

[image]

On Notepad, I can use CTRL A > Find and replace > "First_Name " > "" > And I got a list of names
It's simple when the file have only a few simple names that repeat etc. "Apple iPhone 12", "Apple iPhone 13", ...

How do I do that in Python? It's possible? Each result must be one under the other \n - imo that's the easiest way to paste results into .csv file. Should I append content my .txt file to list and using slicing? Split .txt file?

```
f = open("text.txt", "r")
a = f.read().split()
a1 = a[1:]
print(a)
print(a1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```py
with open("sample.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
    for line in f:
        separate_words = line.split(" ")
        new_line = " ".join(separate_words[1:])
        print(new_line, end="")
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py
iPhone 14
Galaxy S22
Redmi 9
Doe
```

Answer (score 1):

This is concise and uses regular expressions.

## Input: `text.txt`

```
Apple iPhone 14
Samsung Galaxy S22
Xiaomi Redmi 9
John Doe
```

## Code

```py
import pathlib
import re

data = pathlib.Path('text.txt').read_text()
for line in data.splitlines():
    print(re.match('\w+ (.+)', line).group(1))
```

## Output

```
iPhone 14
Galaxy S22
Redmi 9
Doe
```